# strange output using replace() function

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a character (for ex A) in a file with a set of characters as this *NC@@(C)C(=O)O*
The code I wrote is:

```
# Read in the file
with open('C:/in.txt', 'rt') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the character with coresponding code

filedata = filedata.replace('A','N[C@@]([H])(C)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('R','N[C@@]([H])(CCCNC(=N)N)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('N','N[C@@]([H])(CC(=O)N)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('D','N[C@@]([H])(CC(=O)O)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('C','N[C@@]([H])(CS)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('E','N[C@@]([H])(CCC(=O)O)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('Q','N[C@@]([H])(CCC(=O)N)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('G','NCC(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('H','N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('I','N[C@@]([H])([C@]([H])(CC)C)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('L','N[C@@]([H])(CC(C)C)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('K','N[C@@]([H])(CCCCN)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('M','N[C@@]([H])(CCSC)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('F','N[C@@]([H])(Cc1ccccc1)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('P','N1[C@@]([H])(CCC1)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('S','N[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('T','N[C@@]([H])([C@]([H])(O)C)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('W','N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]c2c1cccc2)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('Y','N[C@@]([H])(Cc1ccc(O)cc1)C(=O)O')
filedata = filedata.replace('V','N[C@@]([H])(C(C)C)C(=O)O')


# Write the file out
with open('C:/out.txt', 'wt') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

The in.txt file is:

```
AAA
RRR
NNN
DDD
CCC
EEE
QQQ
```

The problem is that it generates a larger/stranger output then I would expect. For AAA I would expect it to be:

```
N[C@@]([H])(C)C(=O)ON[C@@]([H])(C)C(=O)ON[C@@]([H])(C)C(=O)O
```

But I am getting:

```
N[N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)ON[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)N)N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)O[N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O)N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)ON[N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)ON[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)N)N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)O[N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O)N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)ON[N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)ON[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)N)N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)O[N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O)N[C@@]([N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O])(CN[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O)C(=O)O(=O)O
```

What am I missing?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What is this syntax? What does it represent? Edit: ah it's chemistry formulae?

Comment: Indeed: SMILES code

Answer (score 1):

When your code runs:

```py
filedata = filedata.replace('A','N[C@@]([H])(C)C(=O)O')
```

It puts an `N`, a `C`, another `H`, and two more `C`s into the string. These are then picked up and replaced by the future replaces.

---

The typical way to do this is to operate one line at a time.

```py
def do_replace(line):
    # your replace logic from above

with open(r"C:\in.txt", 'r') as inf, open(r"C:\out.txt", 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        new_line = do_replace(line)
        outf.write(new_line)
```

However you can also use `str.translate` with a translation dictionary.

```py
mapping = {
    'A': 'N[C@@]([H])(C)C(=O)O',
    'R': 'N[C@@]([H])(CCCNC(=N)N)C(=O)O',
    'N': 'N[C@@]([H])(CC(=O)N)C(=O)O',
    'D': 'N[C@@]([H])(CC(=O)O)C(=O)O',
    'C': 'N[C@@]([H])(CS)C(=O)O',
    'E': 'N[C@@]([H])(CCC(=O)O)C(=O)O',
    'Q': 'N[C@@]([H])(CCC(=O)N)C(=O)O',
    'G': 'NCC(=O)O',
    'H': 'N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]cn1)C(=O)O',
    'I': 'N[C@@]([H])([C@]([H])(CC)C)C(=O)O',
    'L': 'N[C@@]([H])(CC(C)C)C(=O)O',
    'K': 'N[C@@]([H])(CCCCN)C(=O)O',
    'M': 'N[C@@]([H])(CCSC)C(=O)O',
    'F': 'N[C@@]([H])(Cc1ccccc1)C(=O)O',
    'P': 'N1[C@@]([H])(CCC1)C(=O)O',
    'S': 'N[C@@]([H])(CO)C(=O)O',
    'T': 'N[C@@]([H])([C@]([H])(O)C)C(=O)O',
    'W': 'N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]c2c1cccc2)C(=O)O',
    'Y': 'N[C@@]([H])(Cc1ccc(O)cc1)C(=O)O',
    'V': 'N[C@@]([H])(C(C)C)C(=O)O',
}

with open(r'C:\in.txt') as inf:
    text = inf.read()

with open(r'C:\out.txt') as outf:
    outf.write(text.translate(mapping))
```